# Ruby on rails - adding several radio buttons to the same line in a form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

How do I create a form where there are several radio buttons on the same line? I can only seem to get them to display vertically, one below the other. I have limited experience with HTML/CSS/RoR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by wrapping them in an element with display style `inline`.

For instance,​

```
<div style="display:inline">
    <input type="radio" name="example" id="radio1" />
    <label for="radio1">Radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="example" id="radio2" />
    <label for="radio2">Radio 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="example" id="radio3" />
    <label for="radio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Will look like this:

> o Radio 1 o Radio 2 o Radio 3

Comment: Would there be a reason why this doesn't work for text_fields?  I've tried this approach and variations to no avail.

Comment: @JakeSmith not sure, here's an example using both text areas and text fields: http://jsfiddle.net/2s2kQ/1/ .. could be an issue with some external css (ie, you are expanding outside your grid etc)

Comment: Do you know if using a form_for rails form might have anything to do with it?  The only thing I seem to be able to change is the length of each text input.  It's like I can't touch the elements in a rails form.